# Spring LDAP: No matching response control found - looking for 'class javax.naming.ldap.PagedResultsResponseControl

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

When I try to use PagedResultsDirContextProcessor to get users from an LDAP-Server I always get
`No matching response control found - looking for 'class javax.naming.ldap.PagedResultsResponseControl`
for every request even though I can find PagedResultsResponseControl.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing a null check before retrieving the attribute's value. This is how I resolved it.

```
if(attributes.get("name") != null){
   model.setName(attributes.get("name").get().toString());
}
```